# XML file returns empty

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I'm working on a project where I want a user to be able to save a string as XML.The program is able to load XML file into the program but is unable to save as XML.
I have previously been doing the this project on C# and I want the exact same functionality in vb.net

Here is my vb.net code to save as XML file:

This is on button click:

```vb
  Private Sub ExportToXMLFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportToXMLFileToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Try
            If (SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
                Dim thefilename As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
                SaveXML(thefilename)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error in exporting XML")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This is the SaveXML function:

```vb
Private Sub SaveXML(ByVal fileName As String)
        'Animal array
        Dim staff As String = staffForm.TheName
        Dim staffmgr As ListManager(Of String) = New ListManager(Of String)
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        Do While (index < staffmgr.Count)
            staff = staffmgr.GetAt(index)
            index = (index + 1)
        Loop
        Dim XMLSerial As XMLSerializerUtillity = New XMLSerializerUtillity
        XMLSerial.SerializeToFile(fileName, staff)
    End Sub
```

XMLSerializerUtillity class and SerializeToFile function:

```vb
Public Class XMLSerializerUtillity
        Public Function SerializeToFile(Of T As {Class})(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal obj As T) As Boolean
            Dim file As Boolean = True
            Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
            Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(filePath)
            Try
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj)
            Finally
                If (Not (writer) Is Nothing) Then
                    writer.Close()
                End If
            End Try
            Return file
        End Function
```

The problem is that the XML file that is created after saving is empty. It doesn't save any string as intended.

Does anyone know the problem and how to fix it?

If necessary I can include the C# code that worked. It's basically the same code that I have "translated" into vb.net code.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the C# code that works:

button click:

```cs
 private void exportToToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string thefilename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                SaveXML(thefilename);
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error in exporting XML");
            }
        }

 private void SaveXML(string fileName)
        {
            //Animal array
            string staff = staffForm.TheName;
            ListManager<string> staffmgr = new ListManager<string>();
            for (int index = 0; index < staffmgr.Count; index++)
            {
                staff = staffmgr.GetAt(index);
            }
            XMLSerializerUtillity XMLSerial = new XMLSerializerUtillity();
            XMLSerial.SerializeToFile(fileName, staff);
        }




 public class XMLSerializerUtillity
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// Serialize to XML
       /// </summary>
       /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
       /// <param name="the filePath"></param>
       /// <param name=" the obj"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
        public bool SerializeToFile<T>(string filePath, T obj)
        {
            bool file = true;

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
            try
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)

                    writer.Close();
            }

            return file;
        }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

When I tried: `serializer.Serialize(writer, "Hello")` I does work.
However, what I want it to do is saving what is in a StaffForm.TheName property

Comment: Did you add the `Serializable` attribute to your `ListManager` class?

Comment: @ppetrov seeing it in a lot of code doesn't make `Serializable` necessery. It is used by *BinaryFormetter* not by *XmlSerializer*

Comment: Hmm, your VB.NET code works for me.  Calling `SerializeToFile("C:\Dev\SO\Serialize.xml", "Hello VB")` results in a file containing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string>Hello VB</string>`.

Comment: @Eser I'm just used to work with the BinaryFormatter rather than with XML, assumed it worked the same way

Comment: @Mark In my program, the string that is supposed to be saved comes from a lisbox. Maybe that is the problem? The user is not supposed to write the string directly in the code like `SerializeToFile("C:\Dev\SO\Serialize.xml", "Hello VB")`. The string that is supposed to be saved is in a listbox

Comment: You creates new ListManager. It has length == 0. Empty list - empty xml.

Comment: I don't believe that C # code works.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov It does work. I takes the string from a listbox and saves it to a filepath.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I tried passing an empty string and `Nothing` to the function, and I still get some XML out of it.  The `staff` variable is also initialized to something (perhaps null).  I also tried his C# code, and that worked too.  I guess something else is going on - perhaps John is looking at the wrong file, perhaps something else - I don't think we have all the details to know.

Comment: Variable `staff` gets only last value from `staffmgr`. Use `+=` instead of `=` at least.

Comment: @Mark I tried SerializeToFile(writer, "Hello"). It does work. However, I want it to save the string that is in StaffForm.TheName property.

Comment: @John.P Do you get a totally empty file, or does it contain some XML, just not the value you are expecting?

Comment: @Mark It contains `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string d1p1:nil="true" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />`

Comment: @Mark What I want it to contain is: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string>thestring</string>`

Comment: @John.P That means your staff variable is `Nothing` - that could be that `staffForm.TheName` is `Nothing` or that your loop is overwriting the value.  You should step through the code in debug and see what is going on with the values.

Comment: @Mark Alright thanks I'll check it through.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for you help. The problem was exactly as you predicted; The staff variable was `Nothing`. I solved the problem now. Thank you again for your help!